# Signed and unsigned don't work

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  signed int a = 5;
  unsigned int b = -5;

  printf("%d\n", a);
  printf("%d\n", b);

  return 0;
}
```

and I get:

```
5
-5
```

So I don't understand why `signed` and `unsigned` don't work, should I get an error?

Comment: you are treating them as signed integers in your `printf`, if you want to print unsigned int you need to write `printf("%u\n", b);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use correct format specifiers that to get the correct result using function printf. Write

```
  printf("%d\n", a);
  printf("%u\n", b);
```

The function simply interpretates internal representations of data according to the format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Use Format spcifier of *unsigned int* which is `%u`

Now compile and run the code you will see the difference

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
      signed int a = 5;
      unsigned int b = -5;

      printf("%d\n", a);
      printf("%u\n", b);

      return 0;
    }
```